# Remove url segment if other segment matches string .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have urls like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/account/home
http://www.domain.com/account/settings/email
http://www.domain.com/account/widget
http://www.domain.com/account/widget/2
http://www.domain.com/account/...
```

I would like to rewrite the url only when **widget** is in the 2nd segment and for it to be rewritten without the 1st segment **account** like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/widget
http://www.domain.com/widget/2
http://www.domain.com/widget/...
```

How would I go about doing this? I know how to remove **account** entirely but not selectively.

NB **account** is a subfolder that my website resides in.

**[EDIT]**

I have found this to work, is this the best way to do it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^account/widget/(.*)$ /widget/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^account/widget/(.*)$ /widget/$1 [L]
```